# How to deal with potentially long operation in a doGet or a doPost?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-applications, servlets, timeout

After an HTTP POST (generated by an application, not by users) I want to send an email.  I got the email sending procedure right but I'm not sure about how Java webapp servers are working.

I'm particularly concerned by timeouts and I want to know if I'm somehow blocking an important thread.

If I do something like the following:

```
    @Override
    public void doPost(
            final HttpServletRequest req,
            final HttpServletResponse resp
    ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.write( ... );
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        // Here I'm sending an email, this can potentially
        // block until the email send procedure times out
        // (the timeout is set to 5 seconds)
        sendEmail(...);
    }
```

And if the email server is down, the thread will block until my *sendEmail* times out (timeout which I set to a few seconds).

Which thread am I then blocking?  I mean, obviously I realize I'm blocking the thread that is processing this POST but is this an issue?  What is this thread supposed to do next?

I read that I shouldn't create new threads from a Java webapp server, so I take it I shouldn't do the following right?

```
    Thread t = new Thread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sendEmail();
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Note that my question ain't specific to email sending: I want to understand what has to be taken care of in a Java webapp everytime you plan to do a potentially blocking/long operation after a GET or a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to start a thread inside a servlet, you just need to be very careful to make sure it dies when the servlet is undeployed.

The easiest way to do this would be to create a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` when the servlet starts and shut it down when the servlet is destroyed. You can then submit your email jobs to the executor service and return from `doPost`. Note that some emails may not get sent if the servlet is destroyed after a job is queued.

In code:

```
class EmailServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ExecutorService emailSender;

    public void init() {
        emailSender = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    }

    public void destroy() {
        emailSender.shutdownNow();
    }

    public void doPost(...) {
        ...
        emailSender.execute(new Runnable() {public void run() {sendEmail();}});
    }
}
```

Comment: when is the servlet undeployed? For example when I undeploy and redeploy the .war?  If I don't make sure it dies, then Tomcat would have more and more threads doing nothing anymore every time I was to undeploy/redeploy my .war without restarting Tomcat?  (am I understanding this correctly ? ;)

Comment: It depends on the container, but undeploying and redeploying the .war should call `destroy`. You can probably rely on he container doing things right (but it won't hurt to put some logging in to make sure). I'd be very surprised if you get two calls to `init` on a single servlet instance because that would not meet the servlet specification.

Answer (score 1):

My advice: store the tasks you need to do (i.e. in a database or queue) to process them in the background by a second process and make your `doPost`/`doGet` return as soon as possible.  Users do not want to wait.

For example, you could receive the external app requests, store the email you need to send in a database or put it into a JMS queue (many application servers come with JMS features but I've never used them), and return.  Other process could be reading that database/queue and sending emails without blocking HTTP responses.

About using Threads in your webapp, it will work and it is probably the simplest solution, but it could also have scalability issues. If you go that way, make sure you use some kind of thread pool (`ExecutorService` ...) because web servers/operating systems usually have a limit on the number of threads.

Comment: for example I could put the email requests from all the POSTs on a queue and have another (unique) thread dequeue them and send them.  But this means I've got to spawn at least one other thread.  Is this OK to do so?

Comment: in my case it's not users but another application performing the POST.  But, anyway, where these POSTs sent by users, aren't the users getting the page back as soon as I close the stream? (which I do before trying to send the email)

Comment: Yes, but even if the application gets the response back, your server could still be facing scalability issues.  It probably depends on the server configuration, but imagine what could happen if your server is configured to support 500 simultaneous requests and you ran out of slots because all of them are sending emails...

Comment: gotcha! It's for a very simple use case so I'll try to keep it simple.  I was considering using another app only to consume/send the emails (the text in the email are stored anyway in a DB) but then I was wondering if I could keep it "small" by doing it directly from the Webapp (hence saving me from having to build/deploy/maintain two apps).  I'll make sure to use one and only one thread to send all these emails and to correctly stop that thread when the .war is undeployed.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great, try to keep it as simple as possible.